# Android Kotlin mapOf containsKey is returning false

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this code in which I created a map of string to a custom class.

I can't access a value from a key and I don't understand why. I tested it on Kotlin Playground and it works correctly but in my code, it's not working.

Can you help me to understand why, please?

```
data class GetInvitationError(
    val message: String,
    val cta: String? = null
)

val getInvitationErrors: Map<String, GetInvitationError> = mapOf(
    "ERR_GINV_601" to GetInvitationError(message = "the invitation does not exist"), // Nothing To Do - No Action Needed NAN
    "ERR_GINV_602" to GetInvitationError(message = "error occured when getting information about organization", cta = "Try again"),
    "ERR_GINV_603" to GetInvitationError(message = "the invitation is no longer active"), // NAN
    "ERR_GINV_604" to GetInvitationError(message = "the invitation is outdated"), // NAN
    "ERR_GINV_605" to GetInvitationError(message = "error when encoding the response", cta = "Try again"),
    "ERR_GINV_606" to GetInvitationError(message = "the invited member is not the signed member", cta = "Sign Out"),
    "ERR_GINV_607" to GetInvitationError(message = "error when encoding the response", cta = "Try again"),
    "ERR_GINV_608" to GetInvitationError(message = "error when encoding the response", cta = "Try again")
)

@Composable
fun ErrorEncoded(errorCode: String) {
    Log.d("ErrorEncoded", "code $errorCode")
    var giError: GetInvitationError? = null
    try {
        Log.d("ERRORENCODED", getInvitationErrors.toString())
        Log.d("ErrorEncoded", "COntainsKey : ${getInvitationErrors.containsKey(errorCode)}")
        giError = getInvitationErrors[errorCode]!!
        Log.d("ErrorEncoded", "Getting value : $giError")
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        Log.d("ErrorEncoded", e.message, e.cause)
    }

    Scaffold {}
```

Here is the logs

```
2023-05-26 06:01:42.516  2352-2352  ErrorEncoded            com.                   D  code ERR_GINV_601
2023-05-26 06:01:42.516  2352-2352  ERRORENCODED            com.                   D  {ERR_GINV_601=GetInvitationError(message=the invitation does not exist, cta=null), ERR_GINV_602=GetInvitationError(message=error occured when getting information about organization, cta=Try again), ERR_GINV_603=GetInvitationError(message=the invitation is no longer active, cta=null), ERR_GINV_604=GetInvitationError(message=the invitation is outdated, cta=null), ERR_GINV_605=GetInvitationError(message=error when encoding the response, cta=Try again), ERR_GINV_606=GetInvitationError(message=the invited member is not the signed member, cta=Sign Out), ERR_GINV_607=GetInvitationError(message=error when encoding the response, cta=Try again), ERR_GINV_608=GetInvitationError(message=error when encoding the response, cta=Try again)}
2023-05-26 06:01:42.516  2352-2352  ErrorEncoded            com.                   D  COntainsKey : false
2023-05-26 06:01:42.516  2352-2352  ErrorEncoded            com.                   D  null
```

My questions are:

**Why is containsKey returning `false`?**

**Why does getInvitationErrors[errorCode] return `null`?**

Comment: Maybe your map key or the string you’re passing to it has a zero width space or other weird invisible character in it. You could try checking equality with the passed String. `val keyMatches = errorCode == getInvitationErrors.keys.first()`

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you, you were right. the error was due to some weird invisible characters. I fixed the error by using `trim()`